# MySQL with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.ios

I'm quite new at using Monotouch and I want to make an app that can connect to my personal MySQL server at home.

I know how to do it in VS2010, but is it possible in MonoTouch?

It will be really helpful if you have a example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I am not sure if you can access a MySQL database directly from Monotouch or not.

However, even if you could, unless you are just using the database on your home network, it probably isn't a very good idea to expose your database to the internet.

I would suggest creating a web service using Visual Studio that performs all of the database interaction. You can then just expose the functionality that you need through the web service and use that web service interface from Monotouch.

Although there will be a bit of a learning curve to start with, this will definitely be a better long term solution.

Comment: Thank you. That's an great solution. Do you by any chance no if there's an place there i can get an web service hosted, so i dosn't need to have an Microsoft Server running just for the small iPhone App.

Comment: I don't know of any that I can recommend since we host our own servers, but I know there are a lot out there. A quick search on SO should yield some good references.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to host an small server at Amazon Cloud, where i have both my web service and an SQL server running. An bonus to that it's quit cheap. From my iPhone App im using WCF communication.